# SQL Server não conecta no SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

Gente, só estou vindo aqui pois já tentei de tudo mesmo, todos os passos no site da Microsoft para esse tipo de problema eu já tentei, baixei o SQL Server 2017 e posteriormente baixei o Microsoft SQL Management Studio 18, porém toda vez que tento me conectar aparece o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já vi os videos do youtube pedindo para ir em Serviçoes e clicar com o botão direito do mouse em iniciarr tudo que é SQL, não adiantou.
Já fui nas configurações do Firewall e crie regras para entrada e saida usando a porta 1433 e não deu certo, quando fui para o proximo conselho que diz para ir no SQL Configuration Manager em Serviçoes está tudo sendo executado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém quando sigo o próximo passo que me pede para ir até Configuração de Rede do SQL Server, em todos os tutoriais que vi, quando clicavam nessa parte apareciam 3 protocolos que poderiam ser habilitados ou desabilitados, porém no meu não apareci nada:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então fui no setup do SQL Serve 2017 e pedi para iniciar um reparo, no final foi gerado um relatorio e nesse relatorio, notei que todos os recursos que poderia usar no Database Engine do Microsoft SQL Management Studio 18 não estavam configurados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando tento me conectar no modo Analysis Services consigo sem nenhum problema, porém estou fazendo um curso em Data Science e preciso urgentemente reverter isso, não queria ter que desisntalar tudo que já baixei pois minha internet é de dados , alguém conseguiria me ajudar com isso? sou muito leiga em instalar programas que precisam de um conhecimento mais aprofundado em computação, desde já agradeço..

Answer (score 0):

Olá,
verifique se nos serviços do windows vc encontra o SQL como na imagem abaixo e caso sim veja se o mesmo esta como rodando. Caso não encontre provavelmente você não instalou a instancia do sql server.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Wellynton, mas não me apareceu essa opção na hora de escolher as instancias e também não achei na internet a opção de baixa-la, consegue me explicar como faço isso?

Comment: Baixe o SQLServer Express aqui. https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql-server/sql-server-downloads

Comment: Mas Reginaldo, eu não tenho como baixar outro sql, já gastei mais de 10gb baixando esse,não consigo baixar apenas a instancia que falta?

Comment: Depois de altos e baixos consegui baixando o express como vc recomendou, muito obrigada \õ/